# Type 'IArguments' is not an array type

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to create a custom logger. Pretty simple but I'm trying to get rid of the errors so I don't have muddy output. I have something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class Logger {
    log(...args: any[]) {
        console.log(...arguments);
    }
}
```

but it gives the following errors in the console:

```
Logger.ts(6,9): Error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

and

```
Logger.ts(6,24): Error TS2461: Type 'IArguments' is not an array type.
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: `args`/`arguments` - typo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The console.log call is incorrect just pass ahead the paramater received:

```
@Injectable()
export class Logger {
    log(...args: any[]) {
        console.log(args);
    }
}
```

Or to print as a real console:

```
@Injectable()
export class Logger {
    log(...args: any[]) {
        console.log.apply(console, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: The second case is the one I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

this worked for me:

```
console.log(...Array.from(arguments));
```

Comment: You don't need to destructure it, ```Array.from(arguments)``` is enough